# Opencart post XML order data

Tags: php, xml, opencart

Im struggling to get a valid order to post XML to another system.
Code's below but not sure where i've gone wrong...
Opencart 1.5.6 and looked at catalog/controller/checkout/success.php

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

<?php
class ControllerCheckoutSuccess extends Controller { 

public function index() {   

// Build the XML Post String
$poststring = "<order_conf>\n";
$poststring .= "<OrderRef>".$this->session->data['order_id']."</OrderRef>\n";
$poststring .= "<Name>".$this->session->data['shipping_lastname']."</Name>\n";
$poststring .= "<CName>".$this->session->data['shipping_company']."</CName>\n";
$poststring .= "<Address>".$this->session->data['shipping_address_2']."</Address>\n";
$poststring .= "<Postcode>".$this->session->data['shipping_postcode']."</Postcode>\n";
$poststring .= "<Phone>".$this->session->data['telephone']."</Phone>\n";    
$poststring .= "<RJ_adaptors>ON</RJ_adaptors>\n";   
$poststring .= "<lines>\n";     
// Iterate through the cart
foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) 
{
$i = $product['quantity'];
$ii = 0;
do {
$poststring .= "<line LineNum='".$ii."'>\n";
$poststring .= "<Item>".$product['model']."</Item>\n";
--$i;
++$ii;
} while ($i > 0);
}   
$poststring .= "</line>\n";
$poststring .= "</lines>\n";
$poststring .= "</order_conf>\n";

// display the string
echo($poststring);
```

Comment: Are You sure that the code inside of `foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product)` is valid? Haven't seen such structure...

Comment: make sure there is no `$this->cart->clear();` before your code

Comment: i have not changed the code but does not always display all fields ?

Comment: @user3497563 like what fields ? what error are you facing. some example would be good to describe your problem

Comment: I get an echo of everything upto orderref and after RJadapters...    
<order_conf>
<OrderRef></OrderRef>
<Name></Name>
<CName></CName>
<Address></Address>
<Postcode>NR1 3PA</Postcode>
<Phone></Phone>
<RJ_adaptors>ON</RJ_adaptors>
<lines>
</line>
</lines>
</order_conf>